# bash find where starting directory has a space

Tags: bash, find, spaces

MacOSX Bash terminal:

`find . -type f`
is straightforward

`find A -type f`
where A is a directory is equally straightforward

However I have a directory
`A\ copy`

(on the system it looks like
`A copy`  of course)

I want to search this as the starting directory, ideally using a string variable for convenience.  Find cannot deal with the space in the directory name... I have tried

```
temp="A\ copy" ; find "$temp" -type f
temp="A copy" ; find "$temp" -type f
temp="A copy" ; find \""$temp"\" -type f
```

and pretty much every other combination in that set you can think of.   What am I doing wrong?    Grateful for assistance and apologies if its a newbie question but I did try to look everywhere on this one.

---

This is the full code so you can see what I am trying to do

```
function find_missing_files_two_input_directories () {

if [[ -z "$1" ]] || [[ -z "$2" ]]; then echo "enter directory" ;
else
firstDirectory=$(absolutePath "$1")
secondDirectory=$(absolutePath "$2")

gfind "$firstDirectory" -type f -printf "%f\n" | sort > /tmp/compare_directory_1
gfind "$secondDirectory" -type f -printf "%f\n" | sort > /tmp/compare_directory_2

diff /tmp/compare_directory_1 /tmp/compare_directory_2 | grep -e ">" -e "<" | tee  /tmp/tmp_compare_output
cat /tmp/tmp_compare_output | sed 's/<//' | sed 's/>//' > /tmp/compare_output
mkdir -p /tmp/compare_validation_copies

while IFS= read -r line  ; do \
echo "$line"
gfind  "$firstDirectory" -type f -name "$line"
#gfind  "$firstDirectory" -type f -name "$line" -print -exec \gcp --backup="t" "{}" /tmp/compare_validation_copies
gfind  "$secondDirectory" -type f -name "$line"
#gfind  "$secondDirectory" -type f -name "$line" -print -exec \gcp --backup="t" "{}" /tmp/compare_validation_copies
done < /tmp/compare_output


\rm /tmp/compare_directory_1  /tmp/compare_directory_2
#open /tmp/compare_validation_copies
#open -a Terminal /tmp/compare_validation_copies

fi
}
```

Comment: Is `-f` a valid flag on OSX ? On gnu find it is not

Comment: You have a syntax error : you want to write `temp="A copy" ; find "$temp" -type f` instead

Comment: Don't escape spaces and other chars in your strings to stop the shell interpreting them, just quote your strings, i.e. `'A copy'`, not `A\ copy`. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Comment: Your second variant, `temp="A copy" ; find "$temp" -type f`, which Aserre also says to use, works for me. What output do you get when you run it?

Answer (score -1):

```
function find_missing_files_two_input_directories () {

if [[ -z "$1" ]] || [[ -z "$2" ]]; then echo "enter directory" ;
else
firstDirectory=$(absolutePath "$1")
secondDirectory=$(absolutePath "$2")

gfind "$firstDirectory" -type f -printf "%f\n" | sort > /tmp/compare_directory_1
gfind "$secondDirectory" -type f -printf "%f\n" | sort > /tmp/compare_directory_2

diff /tmp/compare_directory_1 /tmp/compare_directory_2 | grep -e ">" -e "<" | tee  /tmp/tmp_compare_output
echo "next bit"
cat /tmp/tmp_compare_output | sed 's/<//' | sed 's/>//' > /tmp/compare_output
mkdir -p /tmp/compare_validation_copies

while IFS= read -r line  ; do \


gfind  "$firstDirectory" -type f -name $line -exec \gcp --backup="t" "{}" /tmp/compare_validation_copies \;
gfind  "$secondDirectory" -type f -name $line -exec \gcp --backup="t" "{}" /tmp/compare_validation_copies \;
done < /tmp/compare_output


\rm /tmp/compare_directory_1  /tmp/compare_directory_2
open /tmp/compare_validation_copies
open -a Terminal /tmp/compare_validation_copies

fi
}
```